# format in TCL in not working correctly

Tags: format, tcl

format in TCL in not working correctly,I am trying to format some text and writing them in a file and then sending that file as a mail to user.
I am seeing that format is correct in Linux but when mail comes to user then format is not proper.

## code-

```
puts [format {%-50s%-170s%-50s%-50s} "Test_Id" "Test_Description" "Test_Ran_Count" "Test_Result"]
puts [format {%-50s%-170s%-50s%-50s} $test_id1 "$mail_desc1" $loop_count $test_result]
puts [format {%-50s%-170s%-50s%-50s} $test_id "$mail_desc" $loop_count $test_result]
```

## output-

```
Test_Id           Test_Description            Test_Ran_Count                Test_Result                                       
test_id_1         To execute - test_id_1            10                         PASS
test_id_2         To execute - test_id_2            10                         PASS
```

here if `test_id_2` is big then entire format is shifting,as per format behavior if test_id is less then 50 char then it should not shift other column as I am giving `%-50s` for `test_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Format fields (which Tcl borrows from C's `sprintf()` with very few changes) are a bit tricky. When you use `%50s` (or `%-50s` — the `-` just affects alignment) you are setting a *minimum* field width. To set a *maximum* field width, you might use `%.50s`. Or, more likely in your case, you'll set minimum, maximum and alignment: `%-50.50s`.

Demonstrating with some narrower fields and simple strings of different lengths:

```
foreach str {abc defgh ijklmnop} {
    puts [format ">%-5.5s< |%-5s| /%-.5s/" $str $str $str]
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
>abc  < |abc  | /abc/
>defgh< |defgh| /defgh/
>ijklm< |ijklmnop| /ijklm/
```

As you can see, left aligned, completely fixed width requires giving `%-N.Ns` (for some `N`).